# google.maps.InfoWindow

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am getting my cordinates from mysql database as shown below

```
(<?php echo $_Mylat?>, <?php echo $_Mylon?>)
(<?php echo $_Mylat2?>, <?php echo $_Mylon2?>)
```

When i plot the map, it shows the two points and the direction as shown in the code below

```
    function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: center
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          mapOptions);

    for (var i=0; i<a.length;i++)
    {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map:map,
        draggable:true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: a[i]
       });

    }   
     var flightPlanCoordinates = [
         new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $_Mylat?>, <?php echo $_Mylon?>),
         new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $_Mylat2?>, <?php echo $_Mylon2?>)
    ];
```

i want a message box to come up when i click or hover on the markers for example but it doesn't work, can someone help me to correct the code

```
     var contentstring = 'hey,this is my location'
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow ({
    content:contentstring
    })

    google.maps.event.addListener(??????,'click',function(){
    infowindow.open(map,????????);});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a listener and infowindow for each marker (inside the loop), so it should be something like this (not tested):

```
for (var i=0; i<a.length;i++) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map:map,
        draggable:true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: a[i]
    });

    var contentstring = 'hey,this is my location'

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

}
```

If you only want to have one InfoWindow at a time you should reuse the info window as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows).

Answer (score 1):

Generally infowindows go with markers. When setting the marker, also set the info window and click events.

See [the google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows) for an example of infowindow usage.

Not sure where you are getting a.length from but I am assuming thats the two points of your flight plan.

```
for (var i=0; i<a.length;i++)
    {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map:map,
        draggable:true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: a[i]
       });

    }

    var contentstring = 'hey,this is my location'
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow ({
        content:contentstring
    })

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}
```